# Writer's Block Help

Tags: writers-block

I am in the middle of writing a book but I have serious writer's block any tips on how to combat this? I am only able to write poetry but it isn't as deep and meaningful as it used to be.

Comment: you should search the site before posting; this question looks like it has the answer you are seeking https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/help-ive-got-writers-block?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Take a break, go for a walk, write longhand instead of typing, force yourself to get words on the page, pick up a novel structure handbook, google all the websites online...